# Substituting by one word if the original contains X

Tags: r, stringr

I have been trying to create a new column based on another. I just want to set that if the column includes `"gama media"`, `"bay view"` or `"marina view"`, it replaces all by `"Playa"`. However, with the follow code, I can only substitute one word. How could I substitute all the content?

```
library(rvest)
library(plyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

url2 <- "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g659633-d246401-Reviews-Melia_Salinas-Costa_Teguise_Lanzarote_Canary_Islands.html"
TripHotel<-read_html(url2)

Percepción1 <- TripHotel %>%
  html_node(".hotels-hr-about-layout-TextItem__textitem--2JToc~ .hotels-hr-about-layout-Subsection__title--2a0Ik+ .hotels-hr-about-layout-TextItem__textitem--2JToc") %>%
  html_text()
Percepción1

Percepción2 <- TripHotel %>%
  html_node(".hotels-hr-about-layout-TextItem__textitem--2JToc+ .hotels-hr-about-layout-TextItem__textitem--2JToc") %>%
  html_text()
Percepción2

Percepción <- paste(Percepción1,"/",Percepción2)
Percepción

> Percepción
[1] "Ocean View / Great View"
>

Estilo <- str_replace_all(Percepción, pattern=c("Ocean View", "Bay View", "Marina View"), replacement="Playa")
Estilo
[1] "Playa / Great View"      "Ocean View / Great View" "Ocean View / Great View"

Instead I would like (creating a new column) that the whole column of percepción changes to "Playa" in case it cointains some of the other values ("Ocean View", "Bay View", "Marina View").
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Leti, welcome to Stack Overflow. It will be much easier to assist if you provide at least a sample of `Estilo` with `dput(Estilo)` or if it is very long `dput(Estilo[1:10])`. Please provide the output by [**editing your post**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62046324/edit) and pasting the output.

Comment: @IanCampbell great thank you! I edit the code. Do you know how could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure which one of these two you hope for, but you can pick which one works for you:

First, convert `Percepción` to `data.frame`:

```
library(dplyr)
data <- as.data.frame(Percepción)
```

```
data %>% 
  mutate(Percepción = str_replace_all(Percepción,
                pattern=c("Ocean View" = "Playa",
                          "Bay View" = "Playa",
                          "Marina View" = "Playa")))
#          Percepción
#1 Playa / Great View
```

Otherwise, if you want to convert the whole value, and not just replace, you can use `grepl` and `case_when`:

```
data %>%
  mutate(Percepción = case_when(grepl(paste("Ocean View",
                                            "Bay View",
                                            "Marina View",
                                            sep = "|"),
                                      Percepción) ~ "Playa",
                                TRUE ~ as.character(Percepción)))
#  Percepción
#1      Playa
```

You can also call `case_when` by itself:

```
case_when(grepl(paste("Ocean View",
    "Bay View", "Marina View", sep = "|"),
    Percepción) ~ "Playa",
    TRUE ~ as.character(Percepción))
#[1] "Playa"
```

Comment: thank you so much, it works! (I wanted the second one). Also, is there a way to get just the value, instead of going through a dataframe? As later I have to do a Data Frame like this HotelsDef <- data.frame(Percepción = Percepción, 
                        Data = Data) but with more variables, and it does not enable me.

Comment: Is there a chance to modify the Case_when into an ifelse function, so that when it is not "Playa" it gives out "Urbano" Estilo<- ifelse(case_when(grepl(paste("Ocean View",
                               "Bay View", "Marina View", sep = "|"),
                         Percepción) ~ "Playa",
                   TRUE ~ as.character(Percepción),"Playa","Urbano"))

Comment: Sure, you could use `if_else`, but you can also just change the part of `case_when` at the end that is `TRUE ~ as.character(Percepción)` to `TRUE ~ "Urbano"`.

Comment: Great thanks, and just one more question sorry. The first condition (with case_when) its been done for the column Percepción. If I wanted to add another condition, which would also deliver "Playa", how should we do it? (Example, the other column should cointain "Sol" and if either conditions apply it would deliver "Urbano")

Answer (score 0):

The str_replace_all function takes these separate arguments: (string, pattern, replacement).

Here you have the pattern and replacement arguments both combined in one vector which is being passed to the pattern argument.  These need to be separated:

```
EstiloNuevo <- str_replace_all(Estilo, pattern=c("gama media", "Bay View", "Marina View"), replacement="Playa")
```

(I include the argument names for clarity but they are not necessary).  You can also use the or operator | in the pattern argument: `"gama media|Bay View|Marina View"`

Calling args(function) can sometimes be useful if a function is not behaving as you think it should - it tells you what arguments that function takes.

Comment: it still keeps replacing just one value.